# Magento - Email Shipment = Default

Tags: magento

When creating a shipment in Magento there is a checkbox which allows you to "email a copy of the shipment".

By default this is unchecked.  Does anyone know which file I need to edit to set this 'checked' by default?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/shipment/create/items.phtml**

You can fin there the following lines:

```
<p>
    <label class="normal" for="send_email"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Email Copy of Shipment') ?></label>
    <input id="send_email" name="shipment[send_email]" value="1" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
</p>
```